# Selectpicker with add or delete values

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I've got a bootstrap selectpicker. I've got a list of timeRange values.

```
<select class="selectpicker">

<option data-icon="" value="00:00-23:59">All Day (12am-11:59pm)</option>
<option data-icon="fa fa-coffee" value="05:00-08:59">Morning (5am-8:59am)</option>
<option data-icon="fa fa-briefcase" value="09:00-16:59">Business Hours (9am-4:59pm</option>
<option data-icon="fa fa-moon-o" value="17:00-20:59">Evening (5pm-8:59pm)</option>
<option data-icon="fa fa-clock-o" value="00:00-11:59">AM Hours (12am-11:59am)</option><option data-icon="fa fa-clock-o" value="12:00-23:59">PM Hours (12pm-11:59pm)</option><option data-icon="fa fa-clock-o" value="00:00-05:59">12am-5:59am</option>
<option data-icon="fa fa-clock-o" value="06:00-11:59">6am-11:59am</option>
<option data-icon="fa fa-clock-o" value="12:00-17:59">12pm-5:59pm</option>
<option data-icon="fa fa-clock-o" value="18:00-23:59">6pm-11:59pm</option>

</select>
```

**Usecase:**
I want to add or remove some of them and send the resulting JSON to backend.

This is what I've tried:

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/M69TH/18/
```

I have a button called "Remove" essentially if i click that, I want to remove one of the timeRanges from the selectpicker and re-send the JSON to the backend.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to send the JSON of what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for deleting selected element form the selectpicker:

```
function modifications() {
  $('.selectpicker option:selected').remove();
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

For sending json to backend:

```
function send() {
    var jsonData = {
         name: "value"; //change this according to your needs
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'backend url', //change this
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // any msg you want to display on success
        },
        data: jsonData
    });
}
```

Comment: @TechnoCorner Kindly accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!